# Receiving constant TX RX from Amazon servers upon router restart and ensues

Tags: tls, malware, vulnerability

I had reason to believe my computer was compromised so I used Wireshark and found out that upon restarting my router and before router opens  ports with internet provider it systematically tries to send traffic and create TCP handshakes.

Only when a handshake is executed and router is connected to the internet, it starts sending TLS v1.2 Application Data traffic in and out of my PC, usually the packet size is 1434.

As I would really like to solve this issue and gain info in regards to the originator of this traffic, I lack the time and knowledge to deal with this efficiently, I'm a programmer with very little dev-ops/infrastructure knowledge.

I started with writing an email to AWS abuse, yet I reckon I wouldn't get a lot of traction there and I was thinking about hiring a professional re this.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates any kind of abuse or system compromise. That does not mean that there is none, but only that one cannot draw such conclusion from the few and kind of confusing information you've provided.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So how can I alleviate those concerns regarding unknown IPs that fire upon starting my VTech router?

Comment: AWS is a public cloud service which is used for lots of different things by lots of different companies. This includes software updates, web sites, online gaming .... It is completely unknown what software runs on your system and what it actually does but simply a request to AWS once you are online is not an unusual thing.

Comment: The router tries to send traffic and create handshakes? This is different from your title which says that traffic is coming in to the router. And the router sends TLS traffic in and out of your PC? I think you need to take another try and explaining the traffic flows. It is very difficult to determine what is going on from your description.